# Transactional replication on tablet device

Tags: sql-server, database, replication, database-replication

I have a MS SQL 2012 Enterprise server (publisher & distributor) on a desktop PC which is constantly online (public static IP address) and it needs to do a transactional replication on tablet devices that also contain MS SQL 2012 (Express). Since tablets don't use static IP addresses I'm worried will this work?

I thought on using push subscription, but if tablets change their IP's constantly will this work? Or, should I do pull subscription? Or both will be fine?

Answer (score 0):

The IP address won't be an issue as long as DNS is constantly updated to resolve the correct name/IP.  I've done this previously with fixed devices (desktop PC's).  you may have to bump down the TTL's on those machine names to something pretty low if they reconnect frequently with new IP's.

My .02, I would probably advise against creating a push model at the server because of the dynamic nature of the roaming client.  You might want to create the publication at the server side and use a pull style method.  If the clients are constantly connecting and disconnecting it will most likely aggravate the distribution agent.  If you do use Push you'll want to really consider the frequency of how you build the snapshots and how you handle initializations and expirations.

MSDN suggests the following use cases;
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151170.aspx

Comment: I am also considering pull subscription since the main server is always online and his IP is always the same. Therefore, tablet devices would always have a valid IP address where their distributer agent would check for updates. If I would use push then I'm not sure if the main server would even connect to tablet device servers since they would constantly keep changing IP's. Yes, updating DNS could solve the problem but why to do the extra work...

Comment: You will have to consider something with the tablet device though, how much battery power is going to be use checking in and trying to pull down changes?  Will the merge agent have a high impact on performance with possibly limited resources.  I'm sure looking at impact of battery usage is some what of a unique problem in the DBA world.  Are you expecting to see high transactions and/or large delta's between check ins